# ffmpeg break up videos with frame persecond

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

Theres a command to extract images of a video providing frame per seconds

```
ffmpeg -i "vide.mp4" -vf fps=1 frames/frame_%04d.png -hide_banner
```

Is there a command in ffmpeg to cut video providing fps and save it as video(.mp4 / avi) file like the command above?

What i currently have is i created a method to cut the videos with start and endtime but i firstly created a method to get the length of a video so that i could cut the video base on how many frames that was generated by the above command.

```
 def get_length(self):
        """
        Gets the length of a video in seconds

        Returns:
            float : Length of the video
        """

        print("Getting video length: " + self.video_string_path)
        command = 'ffprobe -i "'+self.video_string_path+'" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"'
        self.command = command
        length = str(cmd.execute(command)).strip()
        print("lenght: "+length+" second(s)")
        return float(length)

def cut(self, start_time, duration, output_file_name = 'output_file_name.mp4', save_to =''):
        """
        Cut a video on a specific start time of the video and duration.
        Check ffmpeg documentation https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html for more information about the parameters

        Parameters:
            start_time : string
                is the value of ffmpeg -ss with the format: 00:00:00.000

            duration : string | int | float
                is the end point where the video will be cut. Can be the same with start_time format but it could also handle integer as in seconds

            output_file_name : string
                is the file name once the file is save in the hardisk

            save_to : string | optional
                is the directory where the file will be saved

        Returns:
            string: file location of the cutted video

        """

        self.make_sure_save_dir_exits(save_to)
        print('Cutting ' + self.video_string_path + ' from ' + start_time + ' to ' + str(duration))
        print('Please wait...')
        file = '"' + self.save_to + output_file_name + '"'
        command = 'ffmpeg -i "' + self.video_string_path + '" -ss ' + str(start_time) + ' -t ' + str(duration) + ' -c copy -y ' + file
        self.command = command
        cmd.execute(command)

        file_loc = self.get_save_to_dir() + output_file_name
        print('Done: Output file was saved to "' + file_loc + '"')

        return file_loc + output_file_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss {start_time} -t {duration} -i "vide.mp4" -vf fps=X -c:a copy out.mp4
```

where X is your output framerate.

---

To segment the entire file,

```
ffmpeg -i "vide.mp4" -vf fps=X
  -f segment -segment_time {duration} -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*{duration}) 
  -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time_delta 1.0 -c:a copy out%d.mp4
```

Comment: Hi Mulvya, is there a way to divide the whole video automatically and just specify the length  of each cut?

Comment: hi @Gyan. i've tried this command on ubuntu and im having bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

i've asked another question on so for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264687/bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Another way to break up video into smaller chunks is the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i somefile.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 3 -c copy out%03d.mp3
```

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment